Is there a generalization of mode coupling theory?
I am currently reading a lecture on coupled-modes theory and have a question regarding the ansatz:
$$E_\text{tot}=A(z)E_1(x,y,z) + B(z)E_2(x,y,z) \\ H_\text{tot}=A(z)H_1(x,y,z) + B(z)H_2(x,y,z)$$
and
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} E_j^* \cdot (\nabla\times E_\text{tot}+i\omega\mu_0 H_\text{tot}) - H_j^* \cdot (\nabla\times H_\text{tot} - i\omega\epsilon_0\epsilon_r E_\text{tot}) dxdy = 0$$
with $j\in \{1,2\}$.
This describes the coupling between two straight waveguides, but can I generalize this for the case of i.e. arbitrary (curved) waveguides and resonant cavities?
What if I couple a waveguide with a resonant cavity? I can imagine that the perturbations $A$ and $B$ now depend on all coordinates, but how does the integral (see also slide 14) change? What is the correct cross section for a resonant cavity?

This forum prefers one question per post and list of questions even around the same theme are discouraged because you may get only a partial answer.

The underlying assumption in the loosely coupled mode analysis between waveguides is that the coupling itself is a small perturbation so that the shape and dispersion properties of the modes do not change by the coupling. If your guides are curved so that the radius of curvature in either guide is much larger than the propagating wavelength than instead of the "z" variable you can have the $\phi$ angle and apply the couple mode perturbation for loose coupling between the curved waveguide modes assuming that you have the modes of curved guides already.

Thank you for your comment. I do not see it as a list of questions however, because I have to say what a generalization would have to cover, else one might have thought I meant an arbitrary amount of wave guides. And with those generalizations in mind, not one, but all equations would have to adapt.

This answer is quite sobering. What theory would I have to use in the case of the curvature radius being smaller than the wavelength? Because I thought it would only affect the solution to the Laplace equation, so the E-H-fields in a "sharp" curve would have been described by Bessel functions.

if the bend is too sharp you really do not have propagating modes in the bend by which I mean that the bend should be treated as a 3D discontinuity rather than a waveguide. For the latter to make sense you need homogeneity along which it has a complex exponential dependence, otherwise you just have a complicated 3D problem.

As far as I understand it now, I have perturbation theory as long as I can meaningfully define propagation, then for sharply curved waveguides I would have to solve the problem numerically, for example with Ansys. But what if I now couple a resonant cavity with a waveguide? The cavity does not have propagating modes either, but should not be a complicated 3D problem, right?

It depends on the shape and size of the cavity. E.g., you can have a waveguide cavity that is 3 wavelengths long and couple to it through an inductive window in the transverse plane, say, and then it is natural to assume standing waves formed by its propagating normal modes and are loaded by the window inductance. If the cavity is smaller than resonant to its natural modes then you have a basic 3D case but even then if the cavity has a natural symmetry/homogeneity it is natural to expand its internal field in some specific set of "modes".

I don't know what an inductive window is. Has it something to do with an equivalent circuit?
Anyway, it also reminds me of an antenna or dipole oscillator. So in your first case I would only have the field in the cavity and the dipole field without perturbation, right? If yes, then I would need to use the method of image charges to deduce the current and charge distribution on the dipole, right?

check out https://archive.org/details/fieldtheoryofgui0000coll/page/n3/mode/2up or https://archive.org/details/waveguidehandboo0000marc/page/216/mode/2up or https://archive.org/details/principlesofmicr0000mont
